# Do the known Hermite constants hold for complex-valued lattices?

Tags: number-theory, complex-numbers, integer-lattices, hermite-polynomials

I understand that there are some Hermite constants that have been known, e.g., Hermite constant for lattices of dimension 2, which is $\sqrt{4/3}$. But these constants are for real-valued lattices. Do these constants also hold for complex-valued lattices for the same dimensions?

Thanks.